# Will running a keys only query in a transaction slow down reads of that entity elsewhere in the application?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

In my database model I have an Entity that is read very frequently but not written frequently at all. Only the write happens in a transaction.

I have an endpoint that runs a keys-only query to check if that Entity exists **inside** of a transaction. This endpoint is frequently called.

My question is, will non-transaction reads of my Entity be slowed down elsewhere in my application because of my endpoint above? I read that frequently running a transaction that reads/writes a certain entity may cause other reads slower. In my case though, I am only doing a keys-only query and checking if the key exists to determine if the entity exists.

**Summary:**

- Entity is read very frequently (not in transaction)
- Entity is written very infrequently (in a transaction)
- Entity is frequently queried for by a keys-only query but not written to (in a transaction)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your key-only query is inside a read-only transaction (https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/transactions#read-only_transactions), then your check will not slow down your non-transactional reads.

Comment: So are you saying I am correct to assume that my scenario will slow down non-transactional read? I am confused on the documentation because it seems to imply that it will only slow down transactional reads. Notice how it only says transactions: "Read-only transactions cannot modify entities, but in return, they do not contend with any other transactions"

Comment: Read-only transactions will not contend or slow down non-transactional reads.

Comment: If you are reading and writing to an entity in a transaction, will other non-transaction reads of that entity be slowed down? For example, if an entity is being updated in a transaction from one endpoint but a different endpoint is querying for that entity in a non-transaction. Will the non-transaction read have to wait for the transaction to finish before it reads it?